# sqlldr error for optionally enclosed by '"'

Tags: plsql, sql-loader

I have dynamic control file as below in shell script

```
`echo 'LOAD DATA' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'APPEND' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'INTO TABLE TJX_SCR_UPLOAD_HEADER' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'WHEN FILE_RECORD_DESCRIPTOR = ' \'FHEAD\'  >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'TRAILING NULLCOLS' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo '(' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'FILE_RECORD_DESCRIPTOR   position(1),' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'LINE_NO                  FILLER,' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'SCHEDULE_NO              ,' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'SCHEDULE_DATE_TIME       date' \'YYYYMMDD\' ',' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'UPLD_TIME_STAMP          sysdate,' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'SEQ_NO                   "' ${exec_seq} '",' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'FILENAME                 CONSTANT ' \'$FILENAME\'  ',' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo 'STATUS                   CONSTANT "UPLOADED"' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
   echo ')' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl`
```

with above code the shell script also working fine.But when I add `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`next to `fields terminated by` as shown below

```
echo 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
```

I am getting syntax error

```
./tjx_sc_req_upld.ksh: line 109: syntax error at line 216: `(`' unexpected
```

when I remove optionally enclosed I don't get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ending up with unmatched quotes.  You need to do some escaping in order to get literal single quotes:

```
echo 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\''"'\'' ' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
```

You could switch the quotes around to make it a little less ugly:

```
echo "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' " >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_sc_req_upld.ctl
```